# ER_PARSE_ERROR you have an error in your SQL syntax: Selecting entire table from MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I looked at similar questions first, but couldn't figure out how to change my code to get it working. I'm new to Node.js and MySQL. I'm running into this error: 
[image]
My code is as follows (I am connecting okay, just changed host/pw info):

```
    var mySQLpointer, connObj;

mySQLpointer = require("mysql");

connObj = mySQLpointer.createConnection( { 
    host:     "host", 
    user:     "user",
    password: "pw",
    database: "db"
} );

connObj.connect( function(err) {
    if (err) 
        // throw err; or use the follwowing command
        console.log("Connection Error: " + err.stack);
    else 
        // console.log("Connected to DB. :-)");
        console.log("Connection OK! ID = " + connObj.threadId);
});

let sqlStmt = "SELECT * FROM Product-Service";

connObj.query(sqlStmt, 
    function(err, dataSet, fields) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        else {
            console.log(dataSet);
            }
        }
);


connObj.end();
```

What I'm trying to do is to display all rows and columns in my SQL table, I only have 3 rows in there: 
[image]
Ideally, I'm trying to get them to display like this: 
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: actually, using minus as a table name, is the reason why suddenly things become that complicated ;) Don't use minus (you can use it to calculate some things in queries as well, and it just gets parsed wrong when you forget the back-ticks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need backticks around your tablename, because of the -:

`` let sqlStmt = "SELECT * FROM `Product-Service`"; ``

Comment: That was it! I cant believe it was so simple. Why is a dash causing this?

Comment: Limited set of identifiers: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html